# FileNotFoundException at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.GetInfo()

Tags: c#, .net

I have this simple line of code:

```
var entry = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://DOMAIN/MachineName, Computer");
Console.WriteLine(entry.Guid);
```

In reality, the path is supplied by command line. This simple Console App is compiled for testing and in my tests I find that:

- Connecting to my own Windows 7 PC works.
- Connecting to any other Windows XP machine on the network, works.
- Connecting to any other Windows 7 machines on the network fails with:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The network path was not found.
>
> at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.GetInfo()
>     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
>     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.FillCache(String propertyName)
>     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeGuid()
>     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Guid()
>     at GetDirectoryEntryProperties.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\GetDirectoryEntryProperties\Program.cs:line 15

Any ideas?

I am an administrator on all machines, however I did have another issue caused by a Device Lock service which caused an `UnauthorizedAccessException` on interrogation, but in this case I can't even read the Guid of the machine.

Event Log is showing nothing of use.

Luke

Comment: I think you need to change this `WinNT://` for Windows 7 Machines.  this is a shot in the dark Guess.

Comment: I just made a VBS script using GetObject and the WinNT provider and that's fine reading the Guid so something that .NET does it doesn't like. I think .NET forces a RefreshCache on all properties whereas the COM way doesn't. I might force it from VBS and see if any decent errors emerge.

Comment: can you show some more code?  the last line of your Error references `D:\GetDirectoryEnttryProperties\Program.cs:line 15`  and `.cs` is the file extension for a `C#` File   ???

Comment: Hi Malione, this is just the file in which the code (top) lives. Its just the Program class from a test console app.

Comment: I assume that you have physical access to the machine you are trying to communicate with. can you see if the file directory exists for the path name that you are trying to connect to? if that makes sense.

Comment: Did anyone find solution for this ? me too facing same problem.

Comment: Sorry, no. I wind up at this contract soon and I have moved on to more pressing work. I assume some service or child of the Computer object has been locked down so hard it cannot even be listed.

Comment: I believe on Vista and later, you would actually have to change a firewall/security setting to allow remote access to the local WinNT provider.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I came across the same error message for a different situation. Perhaps the solution I found could help you too.

After upgrading to Windows 10, my computer gave a popup error when booting up that looked just like the one you posted. It was a FileNotFoundException at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.GetInfo().

The solution was to copy two strings from one registry location to another.

```
Copy these strings: RegisteredOwner and RegisteredOrganization

From: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

To: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan for coming back to post. I'm not working on this anymore but I might some day be back in that area.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, this worked for me. (Win 10 upgraded multiple times). I was opening the connection with new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.MachineName)) and   I got the FileNotFoundException when calling FindAll()

Comment: Marked as answer based on tburi's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say thanks to Bryan Roach I was able to solve my issues.  I also realize I could set my C# project Build to Platform Target x64 and avoid the error as it would search the 64 bit registry area.  However, I feel it is more appropriate for my application be Any CPU and the program itself being able to fix the issue.

```
string ServerName = "REMOTE_COMPUTER";
PrincipalSearcher pSearch = new PrincipalSearcher();
pSearch.QueryFilter = new UserPrincipal(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, ServerName, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate));

try
{
    foreach (UserPrincipal userUP in pSearch.FindAll())
    {
         //Missing Registry Keys will error on pSearch.FindAll();
         //Either Build > Platform Target == x64 or deal with it.
    }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    if(ex.Source.Equals("Active Directory") && 
       ex.TargetSite.MemberType.ToString().Equals("Method") && 
       ex.TargetSite.Name.Equals("GetInfo"))
    {
        //It's possible the registry keys haven't been moved to x86 location on a 64 bit machine:
        //From: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion (64 bit)
        //To: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion (32 bit compatability area)
        //String Properties need to be present:  RegisteredOwner, RegisteredOrganization
        try
        {
            Hack_Fixx64RegistryForGettingLocalAccounts(ServerName);
            //Recall function or whatever to try again with fixed registry.
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
}
```

Then for the function to copy registry keys to the correct place:

```
private void Hack_Fixx64RegistryForGettingLocalAccounts(string ServerName)
{
    RegistryKey remoteKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, ServerName, RegistryView.Registry64);
    if(remoteKey != null)
    {
        //Get keys stored on 64 bit location
        RegistryKey x64regkey = remoteKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
        string regOwner = Convert.ToString(x64regkey.GetValue("RegisteredOwner", ""));
        string regOrganization = Convert.ToString(x64regkey.GetValue("RegisteredOrganization", ""));
        //Add missing keys on 64 bit OS in correct location for 32 bit registry area. The Wow6432Node is for 32-bit apps that run on 64-bit window versions.
        remoteKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, ServerName, RegistryView.Registry32);
        if(remoteKey != null)
        {
            RegistryKey x86regkey = remoteKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", true);
            x86regkey.SetValue("RegisteredOwner", regOwner);
            x86regkey.SetValue("RegisteredOrganization", regOrganization);
        }
    }
}
```