# Getting FileNotFoundException with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, exception, active-directory, credentials

I have the following code to obtain the full display name of the currently logged on user:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public class Form1
{
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var up = UserPrincipal.Current;
        var dn = up.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it fails at the `var up = UserPrincipal.Current;` line with a FileNotFoundException. What on Earth is going on here? I'm on Windows 10 on a machine that is not connected to a domain. I use .NET FW 4.5.1.

Here's a stack trace

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.GetInfo()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoMachineInit()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.get_Current()
```

Comment: Found weird solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113706/filenotfoundexception-at-system-directoryservices-interop-unsafenativemethods-ia